# IndexOf Method for Multiple Properties in Object Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, indexof

What's the best method to get the index of an object in an object array given multiple of it's properties?

Imagine the following example array:

```
var array = [
    {
        color: 'red',
        shape: 'square',
        weight: 200
    },
    {
        color: 'blue',
        shape: 'circle',
        weight: 300
    },
    {
        color: 'red',
        shape: 'circle',
        weight: 100
    }
];
```

Now I would like to have the `indexOf` the object which `color` property is `red` and `shape` is `circle` which, in this example, would be `2`.

Ideally the function would return the index of the object when a subset of its properties is given like `{color: 'red', shape: 'circle'}` and return `-1` if no index is found.

Comment: @JoelEtherton What I have tried is looping of the array and then also looping over the properties but the part where I am stuck is getting only the index of the item that matches both values. The IndexOf just `color` `red` is different then `shape` `circle`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In ES6, there is the array method [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```
let index = array.findIndex(
    element => element.color === 'red' && element.shape === 'circle'
);
```

Until then, stick to a plain iteration:

```
var index = -1; // -1 if not found
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
{
    var element = array[i];
    if (element.color === 'red' && element.shape === 'circle')
    {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with map and combining the properties:

```
var index = array.map(function(o){return o.color + o.shape}).indexOf('red' + 'circle')
```

Comment: Great, until you have a color named `redc` and a shape named `ircle` ;).

Answer (score 1):

you could achieve this using map array method:

```js
var array = [
{
    color: 'red',
    shape: 'square',
    weight: 200
},
{
    color: 'blue',
    shape: 'circle',
    weight: 300
},
{
    color: 'red',
    shape: 'circle',
    weight: 100
}
];
   
 var res = array.map(function(x,i){
    if( x.color == 'red')
    return i;
           
 })
//then you can filter out results to your needs
console.log(res.filter(function(x){return x != undefined}))
```